# Transform output in json format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

The code below is returning data in a non-json format. I tried transform the output in json but no luck. What am I missing here?

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
}

def map_status(data):
  if(data['install_status']=='1'):
    data['install_status']='Installed'
  elif(data['install_status']=='3'):
        data['install_status']='Maintenance'
  return data

@app.route('/outages')
def Outages():

  url = "https://my-api.local.com/data"
  response = requests.get(url)

  result_data = json.loads(response.text)
  result_data['result'] = map(map_status, result_data['result'])
  
  return str(list(result_data['result']))
```

Here is the current output, which seems to be a HTML or text format (I want to get a json format)

```
[{'install_status': 'Installed', 'name': 'server1'}, {'install_status': 'Installed', 'name': 'server2'}]
```

The format which I'm looking for is like this:

```
{"result":[{'install_status': 'Installed', 'name': 'server1'}, {'install_status': 'Installed', 'name': 'server2'}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried omitting `['result']` when returning the value?!

Comment: Yes, it output is: ['result']

Comment: No, not *returning* `['result']`, but returning `result_data` instead of `result_data['result']`.

Comment: yes, then I get the same error I mentioned to Tenacious `Object of type map is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below working. Thank you guys for point me the right direction!

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
}

def map_status(data):
  if(data['install_status']=='1'):
    data['install_status']='Installed'
  elif(data['install_status']=='3'):
        data['install_status']='Maintenance'
  return data

@app.route('/outages')
def Outages():

  url = "https://my-api.local.com/data"
  response = requests.get(url)

  result_data = json.loads(response.text)
  result_data['result'] = list(map(map_status, result_data['result']))

  return result_data # just result
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current response is still json, just without the first `"result"` object.
You should be able to get the expected response with this (see the last line), but do you really *need* to have it in this format?:

```py
@app.route('/outages')
def Outages():

    url = "https://my-api.local.com/data"
    response = requests.get(url)

    result_data = json.loads(response.text)
    result_data['result'] = dict(map(map_status, result_data['result']))

    return result_data # just result
```

Comment: I tried your sugestion, but using only return result_data I get the following error:

`2021-01-07T14:30:31.226-03:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
2021-01-07T14:30:31.226-03:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] TypeError: Object of type map is not JSON serializable`

Comment: ahh, I missed the map, updated to convert it to a dictionary

Comment: I got the idea, but using dict is breaking the code.. 
`dict(result_data['result']) = map(map_status, result_data['result'])
^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call`

Comment: Almost there! Code is working now but the output is not returning any data. Output on screen is `{"result":{"install_status":"name"}}`

Comment: Good news, I was able to get it working. I just changed dict by list. I'm not sure why worked on this way but it is working. I'm always get confuse about dict, tuple, list on python. If someone knows why it worked with list instead of dict, please let me know